# What's the difference among "in regard to" ,"with regard to" , "concerning" and "as regards"?

Tags: prepositions

What's the difference among "in regard to" ,"with regard to" , "concerning" and "as regards"?

Is there any nuance among them?

Comment: There are nuances, but I don't feel I can characterize them well enough for a full answer. As a hint, I suggest treating "regard" and "respect" as synonyms. (If I'm not mistaken, "spect" from Latin and "gard" from German both mean "gaze" or "sight".)

Comment: "Train your suspicions to bristle up whenever you come upon *as regards*, *with regard to*, *in respect of*, *in connection with*, *according as to whether*, and the like. They are all dodges of jargon, circumlocutions for evading this or that simple statement." Arthur Quiller-Couch, *On the Art of Writing*.

Answer (score 1):

"in/with regard to sth" are variants, "concerning" has the same meaning. "as to" is also possible. Not sure  about "as regards". Yes, "as regards" is used for "concerning" or any variant of it.